# Kendo ui mvc ComboBox: How to send additional or custom data to filter results

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo UI ComboBox (MVC wrapper). In this razor view, user will be prompted to enter the children names depending on the "Model.NumChilds" field. ChildName need to be populated from the server. User need to enter minimum two characters. This information is passed as additional data to server using data method in dataSource.
Here in my java script function "filterChildNamesList" I have hard coded to always send first child input value.

How can I send the input value specific to a child?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
@model Test.Web.ViewModels.ParentViewModel

<script>
    function filterChildNamesList() {
        debugger;
        return {
            cFilter: $("#Child0").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }
</script>
@{
 Model.ChildList = new List<Test.Web.Model.Child>();
    for (int count = 0; count < Model.NumChilds; count++)
    {
        Model.ChildList.Add(new Test.Web.Model.Child());
    }
}
<table>
    @for (int count = 0; count < Model.ChildList.Count; count++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Child @count</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.ChildList[count].ChildName)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px", id = "Child" + count })
                        .Placeholder("Enter 4 characters...")
                        .DataTextField("description")
                        .DataValueField("id")
                        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                        .MinLength(2)
                        .DataSource(source =>
                        {
                            source.Read(read =>
                            {
                                read.Action("GetChildNames", "Parent").
                                    Data("filterChildNamesList");
                            }).ServerFiltering(true);
                        }))
                <td>
            </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request))` and return it as Json from your controller instead of passing additional data. This will automatically filter the result in data.

If you want to send additional data, you can change to

```
Data("function(){return filterChildNamesList('Child" + count+"');}")

function filterChildNamesList(arg){}
```

This will help you identify which send parameter you have called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My facing problem sending the additional data to the server from the view when the data is loaded in the combobox using Kendo MVC Wrappers datasource request.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if this is what you need.

Comment: I thought it will work. But it didn't work. Earlier with every web server request JS function is called. But with your suggested changes "filterChildNamesList" function is called only once and it is never called again when data is requested for populating the combobox.